# AWS Lambda cloudWatch.getMetricWidgetImage is not a function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am currently trying to make a call to the relatively new CloudWatch API `getMetricWidgetImage` from a Lambda function but I keep getting an error that says:`TypeError: cloudWatch.getMetricWidgetImage is not a function`

The function is using Node.js 8.10, I'm deploying/testing from the Web Console and the code is below.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
let cloudWatch = tempCredentials ? new AWS.CloudWatch({credentials:tempCredentials, region: 'us-east-1', apiVersion: 'latest'}) : new AWS.CloudWatch({region: 'us-east-1', apiVersion: 'latest'});

console.log(cloudWatch);

cloudWatch.getMetricWidgetImage(widgetDefinition, function (err, data) {
if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
else {
    console.log(data.MetricWidgetImage);
    var response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'image/png',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'x-api-key'
        },
        body: new Buffer(data.MetricWidgetImage).toString('base64')
    };
    callback(err, response);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you clarify how you're deploying your lambda function?

This can happen if you've accidentally included a version of the aws-sdk (rather than using the latest already provided by Amazon in the container).

The `getMetricWidgetImage` function was only added in 2.318 (end of September; [change log](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/01039b3e5b1299ede23776a9bb56db9aeded1c2d/.changes/2.318.0.json).) So it's likely that any cached version you have locally could be behind.

Comment: I've clarified the question. I'm using `const AWS = require('aws-sdk');` which should get the most recent sdk and I'm doing all of this through the web console

Comment: And I'm assuming from your logs that `console.log(cloudWatch);` returns a long object. It would be a good clarification that `console.log(cloudWatch.getMetricWidgetImage)` is also returning nothing. It would also be helpful if you could `console.log(AWS.VERSION)` which should return  '2.344.0'.

Comment: Also- just for now, maybe drop the `apiVersion: latest`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Turns out Lambda uses an out of date SDK version

Comment: You can solve this, then, by packaging a later version of the sdk with your project.